# Scala: insert Long into BigInt using bit shifting

Tags: scala, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

What I want to do to insert the current timestamp into a number of type `BigInt`. Everything in the BigInt should be shifted to the left to make room for the timestamp. However, leading zeros of the time stamp should be ignored.

What I'm doing at the moment:

```
val number: BigInt = ...
val time = System.currentTimeMillis
val usedBits = 64 - java.lang.Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(time )
val newNumber = (number << usedBits) | t
```

Is there a better way to do this? Especially the third line does not seem to be very elegant.

Comment: If leading zeros are ignored, how will you know how many bits are consumed later by the time stamp? (this has nothing to do with your question as such, I'm just curious about the use-case)

Comment: The timestamp is the last element of the "byte stream" and the only element without a fixed size. So after all of the other elements are consumed, the remaining part has to be the timestamp.

Comment: OK. For your question, given the bir-fiddling you need to do, it seems reasonable. I'm less convinced by the use of BigInt as the data structure to hold a byte strea, but I'm sure you have your reasons!

Comment: It's not really a stream that is consumed or send anywhere, just a number composed of other numbers. The binary representation will be encoded with an alphabet (similar to Base64) and used as a unique id. If you know a better data structure to build binary sequences on bit-level, then I'm eager to know :)

Comment: If it really is bit-level, then no, not really.

Comment: That was my first thought, but then you get to implement bit shift etc. At least BigInt has those

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I followed what/why you are doing the shift with a BigInt, but you can use Strings to define BigInts and that might get you closer to what you want.

For example you had:

```
val number:BigInt = 999   // guessed a number
val time = System.currentTimeMillis   // results in Long = 1465400383430
val usedBits = 64 - java.lang.Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(time)  // results in Int = 41
val newNumber = (number << usedBits) | time  // results in BigInt = 2198289632679878
```

You could instead change the last line to:

```
val newNumber2 = BigInt( number.toString + time.toString )  // BigInt = 9991465400383430
```

To delve int to the difference (it's only 3 bits):

`newNumber.bitLength` = 51
`newNumber2.bitLength` = 54

and the binary

`newNumber.toLong.toBinaryString` = `"    111110011110101010100110000101010110101011111000110"`
`newNumber2.toLong.toBinaryString` = `"100011011111110010111101010001111110011011011111000110"`

Until today, I would have not considered using BigInt to pack bits. But at least in this case it does the job quite well and as a bonus if you use the second method and if you know the length of your numeric strings the values can be extracted easily. Cool :-)

Comment: The .toString wll be quite slow. And I think you mean takeRight(13). And the 13 varies, given time will be different each time

Comment: And more importantly, this just doesn't work. Consider if time resulted in 1. The OP wants the lowest bit of the BigInt to be 1. You have the lowest  base-10 digit as one, which is not the same thing

Comment: Changed my answer a bit. Hopefully for the better. :)